# MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() returns only first frame

Tags: android, video, bitmap, save

I have extracted frames from a video using MetadataRetriever, and have stored all images in an `ArrayList<Bitmap>`. I want to store all of them on an SD card (just for testing purposes).

But when I pull out a folder from the emulator and look at the saved images, all images were of the video's first frame only.

This is how I extract the frames from the video:

```
File videoFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/videos","sample_mpeg4.mp4");

Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse(videoFile.toString());

MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
ArrayList<Bitmap> rev=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

//Create a new Media Player
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), videoFileUri);

int millis = mp.getDuration();
for(int i=0;i<millis;i+=100){
   Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
   rev.add(bitmap);
}
```

And this is how I'm saving them (I'm calling this method and passing the bitmap ArrayList):

```
public void saveFrames(ArrayList<Bitmap> saveBitmapList) throws IOException{
    Random r = new Random();
    int folder_id = r.nextInt(1000) + 1;

    String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/videos/frames/"+folder_id+"/";
    File saveFolder=new File(folder);
    if(!saveFolder.exists()){
       saveFolder.mkdirs();
    }

    int i=1;
    for (Bitmap b : saveBitmapList){
       ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

        File f = new File(saveFolder,("frame"+i+".jpg"));

        f.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

           fo.flush();
           fo.close();

        i++;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Folder id : "+folder_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

When I pull out a folder to see all frames, all of the images were of the first frame of video. Can someone please explain to me what is happening?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried with another video. I've found that I'm not getting blank images, but it's always returning the first frame only.

`MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(long timeUS)` is returning only the first frame, but I want to retrieve all frames. What changes should I make?

How do I tackle this?

Comment: I had tried your above code for getting the frames from video but for me it repeats the first frame for all the rest of frames.

Comment: I had tried your above code for getting the frames from video but for me it repeats the first frame for all the rest of frames.My file duration was 127040(2:07sec) here i splited my video for 32 frames can view all 32 images but as same images i'd tried a lot to fix but no use i don't know where it's goes wrong can you help me by your success full code to get different images without the help of ffmpeg

Comment: should I include anything in AndroidManifest

Comment: can you please help me friend by your code

Comment: @Chaitanya Chandukar see my answer below.

Comment: Have you got any solution for that??

Comment: any solution for this??

Comment: @NavneetKrishna What is the **problem for you** exactly? Asker's issue was their not realising that _"getFrameAt method takes time in microseconds"_... They have good answers below. So, is the new problem that your video is _"always returning the first frame only"_ even if you choose some ahead time?

Comment: @VC.One exactly, it is giving just the first frame only, whatever time frame is passed - this is the issue(i'm already using microseconds)

Comment: i have checked with all answers, all of them is basically about changing the time to microseconds. Now i'm using an ffmpeg library which actually shoots up my apk size from 3 mb to 28 mb

Comment: @NavneetKrishna see if my [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56878875/2057709) helps you.

Answer (score 55):

`MediaMetadataRetriever`'s `getFrameAt` method takes in microseconds (1/1000000th of a second) instead of milliseconds, so in your case it is always rounding down to the 1st frame.

Comment: you have added seven 0's instead of 6 @breenger , Micro 10^-6

Comment: The SOBs should have documented it. Everytime we see timestamp in `long` we assume it is milliseconds. The method document should have said it is different. +1 thanks.

Comment: This should be an answer. Thanks @breenger!

Answer (score 15):

Just convert your milliseconds to micro because getFrameAt get data in milliseconds

```
1 miliseconds have 1000 microseconds..


for(int i=1000000;i<millis*1000;i+=1000000){
   Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
   rev.add(bitmap);
}
```

then your problem is solved..

I created it according to my need.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File videoFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/screenshots/","myvideo.mp4");

        Uri videoFileUri=Uri.parse(videoFile.toString());

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ArrayList<Bitmap> rev=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        //Create a new Media Player
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), videoFileUri);

        int millis = mp.getDuration();

        for(int i=1000000;i<millis*1000;i+=1000000)
        {
           Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
           rev.add(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code works but how can i modify it to get all the frames starting from the first one to the last?.Thanks alot

Comment: @DonnieIbiyemi i have created frames like this. Modify it accroding to your need.

Comment: and what about OOM ! even in small video it throws OOM for array list when set increment to 1000 !!!!!

Comment: I'm new to android studio and want to convert video to frames. For that I used the above code and when i click on "run app", it is not showing any error which means that the code is working fine. Now my question is, how can i see these frames?

Answer (score 4):

```
long time;

    String formattedFileCount;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;

    NumberFormat fileCountFormatter = new DecimalFormat("00000");
    int fileCount = 0;
    File jpegFile;
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bArray = null;
    Bitmap lastbitmap = null; 
    bArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

I am taking Time in microseconds and em getting duration from the Mediaplayer like:

```
time = mp.getDuration()*1000;
Log.e("Timeeeeeeee", time);


                bArray.clear();
                MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mRetriever.setDataSource(path);
                int  j=0;
```

My frame rate is 12 frame/sec so I divided 1/12 = 0.083333 and this is the second's part of a frame  and than I convert my frame sec to microsecond so it becomes 83333

```
                for (int i = 833333; i <= time; i=i+83333) {
                    bArray.add(mRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC));



                    formattedFileCount = fileCountFormatter.format(fileCount); 
                    lastbitmap = bArray.get(j);
                    j++;
                     // image is the bitmap
                        jpegFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/frames/frame_" + formattedFileCount + ".jpg");
                        fileCount++;

                        try {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(jpegFile);
                            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                            lastbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, bos);

                            bos.flush();
                            bos.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
```

Comment: Now this is new Question. plz ans this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204944/how-to-get-frame-rate-of-video-in-android-os

Answer (score 3):

**@Navneet Krishna**

Videos have key-frames (sometimes called "sync" frames). The issue might be that: the first frame is the **closest sync** frame when you use `OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC`...

Try replacing this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

with this (which gets closest-available frame to the given time):

```
Bitmap bitmap=retriever.getFrameAtTime(i,OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Read about: [`CLOSEST`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#OPTION_CLOSEST) & [`CLOSEST_SYNC`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever#OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC).

Code below is untested, but is a general idea of *"how to..."*, so let me now if it helps you...
Result should be one picture per second of video duration. Test with a short video.

```
//Create a new Media Player
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), videoFileUri);

int millis = mp.getDuration();

for (int i = 0; i < millis; i += 1000) 
{
    Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime( i * 1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST );
    if (bmp != null) { rev.add( bmp ); }
}

retriever.release ();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but i'm already using `MediaMetadataRetriever. OPTION_CLOSEST`. Infact the code is exactly like yours. When I used `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` ( [see here](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) ) instead, i was able to get different bitmaps for different time

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to replace the `getFrameAt` method of Android `MediaMetadataRetriever`. **AV_FrameCapture** uses MediaCodec to decode the video frame and use `OpenGL` to convert the video frame as RGB Bitmap. As Android `MediaMetadataRetriever` does not guarantee to return a result when calling `getFrameAtTime`, this `AV_FrameCapture` can be used to extract a frame of video with **accuracy**.

> **Follow below steps to implement AV_FrameCapture**

**1. Add below classes to your project.**

list of classes: `AV_GLHelper.java`, `AV_GLUtil.java`, `AV_TextureRender.java`, `AV_FrameCapture.java`, `AV_VideoDecoder.java`, `AV_BitmapUtil.java`

**2. How to use**

we have provided capture snapshots of the video in two ways. if you want to capture using `MediaMetadataRetriever` then use `USE_MEDIA_META_DATA_RETRIEVER = true`; or else it will capture using `OpenGL`.

Finally call `captureFrame` function with `VIDEO_FILE_PATH`, `SNAPSHOT_DURATION_IN_MILLIS` & `SNAPSHOT_WIDTH`, `SNAPSHOT_HEIGHT`. it will automatically capture a screenshot of that frame.

```
    private AV_FrameCapture mFrameCapture = null;
    boolean USE_MEDIA_META_DATA_RETRIEVER = false;

    private void captureFrame(String VIDEO_FILE_PATH, long SNAPSHOT_DURATION_IN_MILLIS, int SNAPSHOT_WIDTH, int SNAPSHOT_HEIGHT) {

        // getFrameAtTimeByMMDR & getFrameAtTimeByFrameCapture function uses a micro sec 1millisecond = 1000 microseconds

        Bitmap bmp = USE_MEDIA_META_DATA_RETRIEVER ? getFrameAtTimeByMMDR(VIDEO_FILE_PATH, (SNAPSHOT_DURATION_IN_MILLIS * 1000))
                : getFrameAtTimeByFrameCapture(VIDEO_FILE_PATH, (SNAPSHOT_DURATION_IN_MILLIS * 1000), SNAPSHOT_WIDTH, SNAPSHOT_HEIGHT);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        if (null != bmp) {
            AV_BitmapUtil.saveBitmap(bmp, String.format("/sdcard/read_%s.jpg", timeStamp));
        }

        if (mFrameCapture != null) {
            mFrameCapture.release();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getFrameAtTimeByMMDR(String path, long time) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mmr.setDataSource(path);
        Bitmap bmp = mmr.getFrameAtTime(time, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
        mmr.release();
        return bmp;
    }

    private Bitmap getFrameAtTimeByFrameCapture(String path, long time, int snapshot_width, int snapshot_height) {
        mFrameCapture = new AV_FrameCapture();
        mFrameCapture.setDataSource(path);
        mFrameCapture.setTargetSize(snapshot_width, snapshot_height);
        mFrameCapture.init();
        return mFrameCapture.getFrameAtTime(time);
    }
```

> List of classes.

**1. AV_GLHelper.java**

```
public class AV_GLHelper {

    private static final int EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID = 0x3142;
    private static final int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;

    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
    private AV_TextureRender mTextureRender;

    private EGLDisplay mEglDisplay = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY;
    private EGLContext mEglContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
    private EGLSurface mEglSurface = EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE;

    public void init(SurfaceTexture st) {
        mSurfaceTexture = st;
        initGL();

        makeCurrent();
        mTextureRender = new AV_TextureRender();
    }

    private void initGL() {
        mEglDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        if (mEglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglGetdisplay failed : " +
                    GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()));
        }

        int[] version = new int[2];
        if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(mEglDisplay, version, 0, version, 1)) {
            mEglDisplay = null;
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to initialize EGL14");
        }

        // Configure EGL for pbuffer and OpenGL ES 2.0.  We want enough RGB bits
        // to be able to tell if the frame is reasonable.
        int[] attribList = {
                EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };

        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
        int[] numConfigs = new int[1];
        if (!EGL14.eglChooseConfig(mEglDisplay, attribList, 0, configs, 0, configs.length,
                numConfigs, 0)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to find RGB888+recordable ES2 EGL config");
        }

        // Configure context for OpenGL ES 2.0.
        int[] attrib_list = {
                EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };
        mEglContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(mEglDisplay, configs[0], EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                attrib_list, 0);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("eglCreateContext");
        if (mEglContext == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("null context");
        }

        // Create a window surface, and attach it to the Surface we received.
        int[] surfaceAttribs = {
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };
        mEglSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEglDisplay, configs[0], new Surface(mSurfaceTexture),
                surfaceAttribs, 0);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("eglCreateWindowSurface");
        if (mEglSurface == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("surface was null");
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (null != mSurfaceTexture)
            mSurfaceTexture.release();
    }

    public void makeCurrent() {
        if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface, mEglSurface, mEglContext)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent failed");
        }
    }

    public int createOESTexture() {
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

        int textureID = textures[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureID);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glBindTexture textureID");

        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glTexParameter");

        return textureID;
    }

    public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st, int textureID) {
        st.updateTexImage();
        if (null != mTextureRender)
            mTextureRender.drawFrame(st, textureID);
    }

    public Bitmap readPixels(int width, int height) {
        ByteBuffer PixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * width * height);
        PixelBuffer.position(0);
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PixelBuffer);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        PixelBuffer.position(0);
        bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(PixelBuffer);

        return bmp;
    }
}
```

**2. AV_GLUtil.java**

```
public class AV_GLUtil {
    /**
     * Checks for EGL errors.
     */
    public static void checkEglError(String msg) {
        boolean failed = false;
        int error;
        while ((error = EGL14.eglGetError()) != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) {
            Log.e("TAG", msg + ": EGL error: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error));
            failed = true;
        }
        if (failed) {
            throw new RuntimeException("EGL error encountered (see log)");
        }
    }   
}
```

**3. AV_TextureRender.java**

```
class AV_TextureRender {
    private static final String TAG = "TextureRender";

    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
    private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
        // X, Y, Z, U, V
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
    };

    private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;

    private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
            "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
            "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
            "}\n";

    private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
            "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
            "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
            "void main() {\n" +
            "  vec2 texcoord = vTextureCoord;\n" +
            "  vec3 normalColor = texture2D(sTexture, texcoord).rgb;\n" +
            "  normalColor = vec3(normalColor.r, normalColor.g, normalColor.b);\n" + 
            "  gl_FragColor = vec4(normalColor.r, normalColor.g, normalColor.b, 1); \n"+ 
            "}\n";

    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];

    private int mProgram;
    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int muSTMatrixHandle;
    private int maPositionHandle;
    private int maTextureHandle;

    public AV_TextureRender() {
        mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
        init();
    }

    public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st, int textureID) {
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("onDrawFrame start");
        st.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);

        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (GLES20.glIsProgram( mProgram ) != true){
            reCreateProgram();
        }

        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glUseProgram");

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureID);

        mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

        mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

        Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glDrawArrays");
        GLES20.glFinish();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes GL state.  Call this after the EGL surface has been created and made current.
     */
    public void init() {
        mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed creating program");
        }
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
        if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
        }
        maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
        if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
        }

        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
        if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
        }

        muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
        if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
        }
    }

    private void reCreateProgram() {
        mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed creating program");
        }
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
        if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
        }
        maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
        if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
        }

        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
        if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
        }

        muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
        if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
        }
    }

    private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glCreateShader type=" + shaderType);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
            Log.e(TAG, " " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            shader = 0;
        }
        return shader;
    }

    private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
        if (vertexShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
        if (pixelShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glCreateProgram");
        if (program == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create program");
        }
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        AV_GLUtil.checkEglError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
        return program;
    }
}
```

**4. AV_FrameCapture.java**

```
public class AV_FrameCapture {
    final static String TAG = "AV_FrameCapture";

    private HandlerThread mGLThread = null;
    private Handler mGLHandler = null;
    private AV_GLHelper mGLHelper = null;

    private int mDefaultTextureID = 10001;

    private int mWidth = 1920;
    private int mHeight = 1080;

    private String mPath = null;

    public AV_FrameCapture() {
        mGLHelper = new AV_GLHelper();
        mGLThread = new HandlerThread("AV_FrameCapture");

        mGLThread.start();
        mGLHandler = new Handler(mGLThread.getLooper());
    }

    public void setDataSource(String path) {
        mPath = path;
    }

    public void setTargetSize(int width, int height) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
    }

    public void init() {
        mGLHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SurfaceTexture st = new SurfaceTexture(mDefaultTextureID);
                st.setDefaultBufferSize(mWidth, mHeight);
                mGLHelper.init(st);
            }
        });
    }

    public void release() {
        mGLHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mGLHelper.release();
                mGLThread.quit();
            }
        });
    }

    private Object mWaitBitmap = new Object();
    private Bitmap mBitmap = null;

    public Bitmap getFrameAtTime(final long frameTime) {
        if (null == mPath || mPath.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal State");
        }

        mGLHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getFrameAtTimeImpl(frameTime);
            }
        });

        synchronized (mWaitBitmap) {
            try {
                mWaitBitmap.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return mBitmap;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public void getFrameAtTimeImpl(long frameTime) {
        final int textureID = mGLHelper.createOESTexture();
        final SurfaceTexture st = new SurfaceTexture(textureID);
        final Surface surface = new Surface(st);
        final AV_VideoDecoder vd = new AV_VideoDecoder(mPath, surface);
        st.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new OnFrameAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFrameAvailable");
                mGLHelper.drawFrame(st, textureID);
                mBitmap = mGLHelper.readPixels(mWidth, mHeight);
                synchronized (mWaitBitmap) {
                    mWaitBitmap.notify();
                }

                vd.release();
                st.release();
                surface.release();
            }
        });

        if (!vd.prepare(frameTime)) {
            mBitmap = null;
            synchronized (mWaitBitmap) {
                mWaitBitmap.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**5. AV_VideoDecoder.java**

```
public class AV_VideoDecoder {
    final static String TAG = "VideoDecoder";
    final static String VIDEO_MIME_PREFIX = "video/";

    private MediaExtractor mMediaExtractor = null;
    private MediaCodec mMediaCodec = null;

    private Surface mSurface = null;
    private String mPath = null;
    private int mVideoTrackIndex = -1;

    public AV_VideoDecoder(String path, Surface surface) {
        mPath = path;
        mSurface = surface;

        initCodec();
    }

    public boolean prepare(long time) {
        return decodeFrameAt(time);
    }

    public void startDecode() {
    }

    public void release() {
        if (null != mMediaCodec) {
            mMediaCodec.stop();
            mMediaCodec.release();
        }

        if (null != mMediaExtractor) {
            mMediaExtractor.release();
        }
    }

    private boolean initCodec() {
        Log.i(TAG, "initCodec");
        mMediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            mMediaExtractor.setDataSource(mPath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        int trackCount = mMediaExtractor.getTrackCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; ++i) {
            MediaFormat mf = mMediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
            String mime = mf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
            if (mime.startsWith(VIDEO_MIME_PREFIX)) {
                mVideoTrackIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (mVideoTrackIndex < 0)
            return false;

        mMediaExtractor.selectTrack(mVideoTrackIndex);
        MediaFormat mf = mMediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(mVideoTrackIndex);
        String mime = mf.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        try {
            mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMediaCodec.configure(mf, mSurface, null, 0);
        mMediaCodec.setVideoScalingMode(MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
        mMediaCodec.start();
        Log.i(TAG, "initCodec end");

        return true;
    }

    private boolean mIsInputEOS = false;

    private boolean decodeFrameAt(long timeUs) {
        Log.i(TAG, "decodeFrameAt " + timeUs);
        mMediaExtractor.seekTo(timeUs, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_PREVIOUS_SYNC);

        mIsInputEOS = false;
        CodecState inputState = new CodecState();
        CodecState outState = new CodecState();
        boolean reachTarget = false;
        for (; ; ) {
            if (!inputState.EOS)
                handleCodecInput(inputState);

            if (inputState.outIndex < 0) {
                handleCodecOutput(outState);
                reachTarget = processOutputState(outState, timeUs);
            } else {
                reachTarget = processOutputState(inputState, timeUs);
            }

            if (true == reachTarget || outState.EOS) {
                Log.i(TAG, "decodeFrameAt " + timeUs + " reach target or EOS");
                break;
            }

            inputState.outIndex = -1;
            outState.outIndex = -1;
        }

        return reachTarget;
    }

    private boolean processOutputState(CodecState state, long timeUs) {
        if (state.outIndex < 0)
            return false;

        if (state.outIndex >= 0 && state.info.presentationTimeUs < timeUs) {
            Log.i(TAG, "processOutputState presentationTimeUs " + state.info.presentationTimeUs);
            mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(state.outIndex, false);
            return false;
        }

        if (state.outIndex >= 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "processOutputState presentationTimeUs " + state.info.presentationTimeUs);
            mMediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(state.outIndex, true);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private class CodecState {
        int outIndex = MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER;
        BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
        boolean EOS = false;
    }

    private void handleCodecInput(CodecState state) {
        ByteBuffer[] inputBuffer = mMediaCodec.getInputBuffers();

        for (; !mIsInputEOS; ) {
            int inputBufferIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
            if (inputBufferIndex < 0)
                continue;

            ByteBuffer in = inputBuffer[inputBufferIndex];
            int readSize = mMediaExtractor.readSampleData(in, 0);
            long presentationTimeUs = mMediaExtractor.getSampleTime();
            int flags = mMediaExtractor.getSampleFlags();

            boolean EOS = !mMediaExtractor.advance();
            EOS |= (readSize <= 0);
            EOS |= ((flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) > 0);

            Log.i(TAG, "input presentationTimeUs " + presentationTimeUs + " isEOS " + EOS);

            if (EOS && readSize < 0)
                readSize = 0;

            if (readSize > 0 || EOS)
                mMediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, readSize, presentationTimeUs, flags | (EOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0));

            if (EOS) {
                state.EOS = true;
                mIsInputEOS = true;
                break;
            }

            state.outIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(state.info, 10000);
            if (state.outIndex >= 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    private void handleCodecOutput(CodecState state) {
        state.outIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(state.info, 10000);
        if (state.outIndex < 0) {
            return;
        }

        if ((state.info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            state.EOS = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "reach output EOS " + state.info.presentationTimeUs);
        }
    }
}
```

**6. AV_BitmapUtil.java**

```
public class AV_BitmapUtil {
    public static void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp, String path) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap src) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was found an answer last 8 hours and finally, i got it and it is working !! Thank you @Vishrut Mavani .. :)

Comment: @VishrutMavani I just used your code to capture the exact frame of a playing video and this works great. Much, much better than the MediaMetadataRetriever class. Thanks !!!

Comment: @dennieku You are welcome! if you didn't give a vote. then plz give it. 
because it motivates me to post a more helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks, @VIISHRUTMAVANII Saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on your for/loop:

```
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(
    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(i, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), 
    retriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MetaMediaRetriever i was able to get the screeshot of video

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794