# MediaMetadataRetriever getFrameAtTime return first frame only

Tags: android, video, animated-gif, mediametadataretriever

The below code returns(test.gif) only the first frame and makes a gif with the 5 same frames (video first frame).

I read most questions in StackOverflow but I can't figure out what cause this problem.

Also, per some suggestions, I tried to use `mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime` with `MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST` option with no success.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri vid = data.getData();
            videoPath = getPath(vid);

            MediaMetadataRetriever mmRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
            String METADATA_KEY_DURATION = mmRetriever  
                    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);  


            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

            AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
            encoder.setDelay(30);
            encoder.start(bos);

            int max = (int) Long.parseLong(METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            Log.i("max",String.valueOf(max));
            for (int i=1000000;i<max*1000;i+=1000000) {
                Log.i("i",String.valueOf(i));   

                Bitmap bitmap = mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime(i,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);

                encoder.addFrame(bitmap);


            }
            encoder.finish();
            try {
                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "test.gif";
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
                outStream.write(bos.toByteArray());
                outStream.close();
                GifAnimationDrawable big = new GifAnimationDrawable(
                        new FileInputStream(filepath));

                imageview.setImageDrawable(big);
                big.setVisible(true, true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Log return max value about 5000

Comment: I can't understand why this question give negatives? where is problem?i have problem and give details as i can,

Comment: must see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24307619/3496570

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592700/798160) source:

[MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)'s getFrameAt method takes in microseconds (1/1000000th of a second) instead of milliseconds, so in your case it is always rounding down to the 1st frame.

Comment: i update code with: for (int i=1000000;i<max*1000;i+=1000000),it don't work anyway, also 10000000th is incorrect(must contain 6 zero)

Comment: William, what this mean,i use log and i is equal 1000000,2000000,... in each step, is't it correct?

Comment: first frame returns problem, same as what give at first